# JSON: Getting entry with specific value

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON array, in this case it has only three entries, but there could also be more.

```
[
    {
        "id": 45,
        "text": "apple"
    },
    {
        "id": 37,
        "text": "pear"
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "text": "strawberry"
    }
]
```

Now my question is: How do I get the `text` variable of the entry with (for example) `id` being `37` in PHP? Is it possible to get that easily?

What I know: I could use a for loop for finding the text like this (in PHP):

```
<?php
    $fruits = json_decode(file_get_contents("file.json"), true); // First I decode the file
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fruits); $i++) {
        // Using this for loop and if condition, I get the text I need
        if ($fruits[$i]['id'] == 37) echo $fruits[$i]['text'];
    }
?>
```

But I don't want to use a for loop, as my JSON array has more than 3 entries, and if i request a lot of data in short time it takes long time till the for loop goes through every entry. So is there a more effective way to get to the same result? Can somebody explain me this in PHP?

Comment: I think you have to use any kind of a loop to get your information. You could use `array_filter()` but this does also an internal loop.

Comment: Most of the suggested solutions below use a for (each) loop internally thus they won't be significantly faster then your own suggested solution. In case you need to search the `json` data multiple times I would suggest storing them as `key` `value` with the `id` as the key. This is already suggested several times.

Comment: Do you control the data structure Dejori David? Could you make elements sorted by id when you create the json data? if so, you could apply binary search on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can change your json structure then it is possible.

If you create json like this

```
{
    "45":{ 
        "text": "apple"
    },
    "37":{ 
        "text": "pear"
    },
    "22":{
        "text": "strawberry"
    }
}
```

and in php

```
 echo $item['37']['text'];
```

This will help :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php):

```
$yourEntry = current(array_filter($jsonArray, function(\stdClass $entry) {
    return ($entry->id == 37);
}));
```

[**See the example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#CbTNZnt7r)

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
<?php
    $fruits = json_decode(file_get_contents("file.json"), true); // First I decode the file
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fruits); $i++) {
        // Using this for loop and if condition, I get the text I need
        if ($fruits[$i]['id'] == 37) echo $fruits[$i]['text'];
    }
?>
```

to

```
<?php
    $fruits = json_decode(file_get_contents("file.json"), true); // First I decode the file
    foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
        // Using this for loop and if condition, I get the text I need
        if ($fruits['id'] == 37)  { 
        echo $fruits['text'];
        //rest of your code you like to add
        }
    }
?>
```

if you intend to use for loop only then use below code:

```
<?php
    $fruits = json_decode(file_get_contents("file.json"), true); // First I decode the file
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fruits); $i++) {
        // Using this for loop and if condition, I get the text I need
        if ($fruits['id'] == 37)  { 
        echo $fruits['text'];
        //rest of your code you like to add
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Also add a `break;` in the `if` block. To stop the loop if you found what you want.

Comment: You're referencing the `$fruits` as an object when it was decoded as an array. This will throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply with this:

```
foreach($fruits as $item) {
    if($item['id'] == 37) { echo $item['text']; break; }
}
```

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#tTkCtZQxm)

Answer (score 0):

Are you in control of the json data structure? If so, you could change to access via array key, e.g.

```
{
  '37': 'pear',
  '45': 'apple',
  '22': 'strawberry'
}
```

$fruits = json_decode(file_get_contents("file.json"), true);

echo $fruits['37']; // pear